# How to pass command line arguments to tests with gradle test?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, arguments, junit4

I am using gradle to run JUnit tests. The problem is that I need to pass arguments from the command line to tests. I tries to pass System properties but failed.

```
gradle test -Darg1=something
```

Here is my test:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(System.getProperty("arg1"), "something");
    }
}
```

It fails because there is no `arg1` argument.
Is it possible somehow to pass command line arguments?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you run `gradle test -Darg1=smth`, you pass system parameter `arg1` to the Gradle JVM, not the test JVM where tests are run. It is designed this way to protect tests from side effects.

If you need to propagate parameters to tests, use something like this

```
test {
    systemProperty 'arg1', System.getProperty('arg1')
}
```

and run it the same way.

Comment: where should I put the test{ systemProperty 'arg1', System.getProperty('arg1')} script? I get this error: "could not find method test for arguments()"

Comment: @Apperside  check this  https://github.com/cuba-platform/cuba/blob/master/build.gradle#L391

Comment: @ Apperside Put this text in the build.gradle

Comment: how do you set a default value that can be overriden from command line?

Comment: When I add test method linke mentioned above in my gradle file, I get error saying "Could not find method test() for arguments on extension 'android' of type", is this updated recently?

Comment: This works for me on gradle kotlin dsl!

Change build.gradle
`tasks.test { systemProperty("arg1", System.getProperty("arg1") ?: "default value") }`

And then pass the argumet on cli:
`./gradlew build test -Darg1=value`

Answer (score 20):

Use -D to send your parameters in. Like so:

```
./gradlew test -Dgrails.env=dev -D<yourVarName>=<yourValue>
```

See the [gradle command line documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html) of -D.

To access it in the tests, you need to propagate it in your build.gradle file.

```
    test {
       systemProperty "propertyName", "propertyValue"
    }
```

You can also pass all System Properties like so:

```
    test {
        systemProperties(System.getProperties())
    }
```

Comment: I misread the OPs question, and made my edits before I refreshed the page to see your answer.

Comment: He also has "all System Properties" option, which is missing from your answer.

Comment: Could you then use `System.getProperties('yourVarName')` in your Java code to obtain the `yourValue` passed by command line?

Comment: When I add test method linke mentioned above in my gradle file, I get error saying "Could not find method test() for arguments on extension 'android' of type", is this updated recently?