# cucumber-gradle- how to override cucumber tags in runtime

Tags: gradle, cucumber, gradle-task

I have jUnit runner class to run cucumber with gradle with before and afterclass in it.
when using cucumber.options="--tags@fix" still all test cases are running.
Note: I am able to override it in mvn but it's not working in gradle

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"pretty",},
        glue = {"mobile/iag/com/au/stepdefs"},
        tags = {"@fix","~@ignore"},
        features = {
                "src/test/resources/features/some.feature"}
)
public class RunCukesTest {
    //public static String token;
    static WireMockServer wm = new WireMockServer(options()
            .port(8181)
            .httpsPort(8282)
            .keystorePath("src/test/resources/mock/cert/identity.jks")
            .usingFilesUnderDirectory("src/test/resources/mock")
    );

    @BeforeClass
    static public void beforeCucumberTestStart() {
        PropertyConfig propertyConfig = new PropertyConfig();
        if (!propertyConfig.isBatsEnv()) {
            wm.start();
            System.out.println("Starting Mock service.");
            Utils.clearLogFile();
            Utils.clearMockFile();
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    static public void afterCucumberTestEnd() {
        PropertyConfig propertyConfig = new PropertyConfig();
        if (!propertyConfig.isBatsEnv()) {
            wm.stop();
            System.out.println("Stopping Mock service.");
        }
    }
```

I want to run this class in run time by overriding cucumber tag options in gradle. How do I do that?

Comment: You are trying to pass environment variables to gradle test
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492742/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-tests-with-gradle-test

Comment: problem is adding env variables with system properties for cucumber tags is not working..