# How to run test multiple times with different system property via command line in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, junit-jupiter

What is the recommended solution to run a test multiple times with different system properties via command line?

What I would like to do could look like this:

```sh
gradle clean test --tests -Dmyproperty=foo my.fancy.test.TestClass --tests -Dmyproperty=bar my.fancy.test.TestClass
```

I need this parameter for the setup code in the `@BeforeAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you use junit you can use `@ParameterizedTest` which allows you to repeat the same junit test with different parameters.
You would need to move the code for the setup from the "BeforeAll" somewhere else.

```
static Stream<String> testArgs() { return Stream.of(""," ", null,"12345"); }

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testArgs")
public void testByArgs(String arg){
   // Your test with asserts based on args here ...
}
```

Comment: In case my question is unclear. What I need is the passed parameter for the setup code of the test class. I added this hint to my initial question.

Comment: There is no such thing. If you need different setups why don't you write different tests? You can always create a class which holds all the "duplicate" code for test purposes.

Comment: This was my initial idea to write multiple tests. But I thought there is support from Gradle. I will follow your suggestion and write multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also wire those parameters up with tests' JVM through Gradle's test dsl:

```
// build.gradle
test {
    systemProperty 'myproperty', System.getProperty('myproperty')
}

// in your tests use it like:
@BeforeAll
fun setUp() {
  System.getProperty("myproperty")
}
```

Basicailly this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42492911/3225458).

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, then I need to run Gradle for each test separately.